# Exception Value:no such table: appname_tablename?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

I tried all possibilities for this issue in **Django** but it's not resolved at. it will not create **0001_initial.py** I tried many ways.

`python manage.py showmigrations`

`python manage.py makemigrations`

`python manage.py migrate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a new app that does not have any existing migrations you need to create an initial migration by passing the app name to makemigrations

```
python manage.py makemigrations appname
```

makemigrations will not automatically create initial migration files for new apps

Comment: @rajeevpunna Don't forget to accept the answer if your problem is solved. Not in this post only but across all your questions. It helps lot of other people visiting your post. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should first check that you have created your database on settings.py:

DATABASES = {'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3','NAME': 'mydatabase',}}

Next make sure that you have created an app using python manage.py startapp appname

If that is done you also want to make sure that you actually have a database model made on models.py.

Then run:

python manage.py makemigrations appname

python manage.py migrate

Comment: I did all what you said above. At the beginning of my project its created 0001_initial.py but one day I deleted directly. After that I am running makemigrations and migrate but no changes applied its came.